# Powershell Create new shortcut named after website

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to make shortcuts from Websites. There is no problem and it works  with this Code:

```
$WshShell = New-Object -comObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut("E:\Powershell\Ziel\TestFile.lnk")
$Shortcut.TargetPath = "https://www.google.ch/"
$Shortcut.Save()
```

Now I want it to read the URL and create the shortcut with the name "Google" ("www.google.ch" would also be okay).

I'm also trying to read the URL out of my browser, and create the shortcut from that.  What I mean is, when I'm on Google, I want to start the script and have it create a shortcut named "Google".

The important part is the first part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use regex or `String.IndexOf()` and `String.Substring()` to grab the hostname from the url.

But the easiest (and most robust) way is probably to parse the URL as a [`[uri]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx) type object, and then grab the `Authority` part:

```
function New-WebsiteShortcut
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [uri]$URL,

        [Parameter()]
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_ -PathType Container})]
        [string]$Location = (Join-Path $env:USERPROFILE "Desktop")
    )

    # Grab hostname
    $HostName = $URL.Authority

    # construct file name and path from hostname
    $ShortcutName = '{0}.lnk' -f $HostName
    $ShortcutPath = Join-Path $Location $ShortcutName

    # create shortcut
    $WshShell = New-Object -comObject WScript.Shell
    $Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut($ShortcutPath)
    $Shortcut.TargetPath = "$URL"
    $Shortcut.Save()
}
```

Now you can supply just the URL (and optionally a location) to your new cmdlet:

```
New-WebsiteShortcut -URL "https://www.google.ch" -Location "E:\PowerShell\Ziel"
```

I'll leave error handling of existing file names as an exercise to the reader :)

Comment: Sorry for late answer, was busy the last few days.
So this script worked for me great, thanks for that! But i still have the problem that i have type the URL first. Do you have any idea how i could read the current URL which i'm browsing on? Or is that even possible?